# Maya API frame rate

Tags: maya-api

Is there a way to query the frame rate during playback?

I'm writing a simple HUD node and I'd like to include the frame rate, similar to the default maya one found in >> `Display/Heads Up Display/Frame Rate.`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the api but there's a Mel version

playbackOptions -q -fps

Edit: just found this

http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_anim_control.html

Try using playbackSpeed?